# How to find the newest files in directory?

Tags: c, linux

Suppose i have a directory in /tmp/myDir where files are constantly created, modified and destroyed by a daemon.
I need to periodically (every 45 seconds) monitor last created files. To do that i must determine which files were created after the last check.
What would be the best way to do that from a c daemon?

If possible, the method should avoid opening every file in the directory during each check.

Comment: Is [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) available on your target system?

Comment: Are all files deleted after a "check"?

Comment: files are created and deleted independently by other process, that is essentially a black box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inotify` is pretty nifty... If you can't use that, I would suggest obtaining the `st_mtime` for each file in the directory, and comparing it to `(time(0) - 45)`. If it's greater, then it's within your 45 second window. Put your executable on the `crontab` if you're rather not create a continually running daemon.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was really lost as to where even look for relevane functions.

Comment: On that note, Here are two AWESOME sites for searching C functions... http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/ and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/.

Answer (score 0):

call `scandir` and use the `filter` callback function to leave only relevant files. you will probably have to use `fstat` on each one of the files.